# Different design for pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working over word press after a long long time. In my website , I have a number of pages and most of them are of different designs. They all are added under pages but designs will be different for them.

I just want to know the standard way to handle them. Is there any different template scheme to handle different designs of pages ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply place a tag at the top of your pages, say you create a file `my-templated-page.php`, you would tag at the top of that file like so:

```
<?php
/*
*
* Template Name: My Template 1.0
*
*/
?>
```

That will allow you to go into **Pages** and select dropdown box '**Template**' and select your template name `My Template 1.0` . Simple style your `my-templated-page.php` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

No, you simply create headers and footers for every design. If that's what you want.

Every page templates

```
<?php get_header('header_page1'); ?> // it points to header-header_page1.php
    //custom html for Page 1
<?php get_footer('footer_page1'); ?> // it points to header-footer_page1.php
```

[Reference here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header)